# Invalid int: ""?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to save the state of my app and I thought it all looked good but i keep getting this error:

```
10-07 15:18:35.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1818): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

And it keeps highlighting my codes that say:

```
textView(something) = Integer.parseInt(textView(something).getText().toString());
```

Comment: This is one of the longest code-snippits I've seen on an SO question.

Comment: Serious, don't post 1000 lines of code here! - I removed the code as your one line code plus the error is enough to find the issue.

Answer (score 5):

One of your TextViews is blank. A blank String cannot be converted to an `int`. Can you narrow it down to which one (or one of the many) that are causing the problem?

**Edit:**

Most likely this is because you are doing everything in your `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method and the system has not had a chance to initialize the `TextView`s with their text. Such a long `onCreate()` method indicates design issues to me. I strongly suggest separating your code into one or more classes. For example, you might want to create a `Hero` class which represents the user's character in the game. This can store all the stats related to the character. Also a `Monster` class could represent the stats for a monster.

Comment: Ok, I'll go back and redo this... Thanks!

Comment: The most important tip in this answer: `I strongly suggest separating your code into one or more classes.` - I can't agree more...

Comment: @WarrenFaith +1 Thanks for emphasizing that.

Answer (score 1):

Put this before the `Integer.parseInt`.  Then check LogCat for `text="", len=0`

```
String str = textView(something).getText().toString();
Log.i("app", "text=\"" + str + "\", len=" + str.length);
textView(something) = Integer.parseInt(textView(something).getText().toString());
```